# How to define parameters in Liquibase Formatted SQL Changelogs

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

I am having a SQL which is written like this

```
DECLARE @CurrencyIdEUR INT = 1;
INSERT Currency (Id, CurrencyCode) VALUES (@CurrencyIdEUR, 'EUR');
INSERT Price (Price, Currency) VALUES (123.45, @CurrencyIdEUR);
```

I want to add that to a Liquibase formatted SQL, but I don't know HOW to add such kind of parameters. There's a close discussion, but not the "how"-part, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978380/how-to-declare-a-variable-and-mysql-update-in-liquibase) and [here on the Liquibase page](http://www.liquibase.org/2010/05/liquibase-formatted-sql.html) they write, that's it's possible, but not HOW.

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--property name:CurrencyIdEUR value:1

--changeset Stix:123
INSERT Currency (Id, CurrencyCode) VALUES (${CurrencyIdEUR}, 'EUR');
...
```

That's my latest try. I'll be very happy if you could help with the correct parts.

Answer (score 5):

TL/DR: It appears like it is not implemented for sql changelogs - but properties are passed from the xml changelogfile.

I looked into the code of the FormattedSqlChangeLogParser and could not find any references to property parsing.

As a workaround you can enter the properties in the xml changelog file. This will also make the property available for all sql-scripts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog ...>

    <property name="CurrencyIdEUR" value="555"/>

    <include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="DoStuff.sql" />

</databaseChangeLog>
```

In DoStuff.sql:

```
--changeset peter.henell:dostuff-procedure endDelimiter:\nGO splitStatements:true
CREATE PROCEDURE DoStuff
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1, 2, ${CurrencyIdEUR};
END
```

Comment: when running this getting this error postgres  "syntax error at or near $"

Comment: To be able to help you, it is better if you can post a new question with a fully re-preducable example

Answer (score 3):

This feature has been added in Liquibase 3.5.0, which was released today (April 21, 2016)

Comment: Could you please describe which feature you are talking about a little more detailed? Maybe with an example too?

Comment: See this announcement for more details:
http://us2.campaign-archive1.com/?u=c24cd4e0098d3017cc468c324&id=48a133352d&e=6ca7733538

It does not appear that the documentation has been updated yet though. I think the syntax is probably as shown in the question.

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar problem with our MSSQL changelogs and Spring Boot 2.x. The changelog contains a view with schemabinding, where we wanted to make the schema configurable.

SQL changelog:

```
CREATE VIEW foo WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
SELECT * FROM ${schema}.bar;
```

Then in application.yml

```
spring:
    liquibase:
        parameters: 
            schema: ${spring.liquibase.default-schema:dbo}
```

Now we can provide `-Dspring.liquibase.default-schema={YOUR_SCHEMA}` as environment variable and this will be applied to Liquibase changelogs and Spring Boot.

Comment: Is there docs for that?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/property-substitution.html