# Liquibase create sql variable and use it in insert query,

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to execute below query in liquibase but I am getting error message.

```
<changeSet author="AW001TI (generated)" id="1492080265432-37" objectQuotingStrategy="QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS" context="snd,dev,dev1,qa,qa1,qa2,prv,stg">
    <sql dbms="mysql"
         splitStatements="true"
         stripComments="true">
        USE gpptrackingbarcode;
        select @trackingrangeid := (select max(trackingrangeid) from trackingrangeintegrated) + 1;
        INSERT INTO `gpptrackingbarcode`.`trackingrangeintegrated` (`destcountrycode`, `carrier`, `mailservicename`, `mailserviceoptionname`, `shipmenttype`, `custom`, `appidentifier`, `secondaryappidentifier`, `trackingrangeid`, `partnerid`, `region`, `specialservicename`, `mailerid`, `senderuserid`)
        VALUES ('US', 'usps', 'IMB', 'ALL', 'outbound', 'dispense', '00', '310', @trackingrangeid, '0', 'domestic', 'ALL', '902097365', '0') ;
        INSERT INTO `gpptrackingbarcode`.`trackingrangeuspsdomestic` (`trackingrangeid`, `rangesequence`, `startsequence`, `endsequence`, `sequencewidth`, `nextnumber`, `alertthreshold`, `alertinterval`, `lifespan`, `lastrolloverdate`, `activeflag`, `recyclableflag`)
        VALUES (@trackingrangeid , '1', '1', '999999', '6', '1', '100000', '1000', '120', '2017-06-13 00:00:00', 1,1);
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

In above changeset problem is using variable @trackingrangeid. I thought when I use sql tag in liquibase then above query will work but it is not working. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I need to run this type of query in liquibase.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Awadhendra

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare a variable and mysql update in liquibase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978380/how-to-declare-a-variable-and-mysql-update-in-liquibase)